# fire up website on the interent

Tags: web-hosting

I don't know this question is suitable to be asked here or not..dont mind.
I develop a website yesterday and wanted to publish it on the internet. I know `GitHub` is a right choice it is totally free for `static pages` but it won't allow you to upload more than `100` pages.so this didn't work. then I search a lot on the internet for a free hosting website but I did find one which works there are many free hosting websites but they such a mess make thing so complicated. I deactivated `7` accounts from all website.
I waste my time and did publish my site.

so is there no any way to do so.?

Comment: You get what you pay for. Just pay the few bucks and get a quality host. It really does make a huge difference!

Comment: @closetnoc yes you are right and I agree wid you but its very simple portfolio type site and I don't want to pay any penny to get any service.that is why I was searching for free hosting.